# Свойства c# - как работают

Tags: c#

```
class A
{ 
    private int a;
    private int b;
    private int c;

    public int W{get;set;}
}
```

Вопрос: к какому из этих трех полей будет иметь доступ это свойство?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ни к какому из указанных, компилятор создаст неявное поле для свойства `W`.

Если вам нужно что бы свойство обращалось к конкретному полю, это нужно указать явно.

```
class A
{ 
    private int a;

    public int W
    {
        get { return a; }
        set { a = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо за помощь!